# mysqli connection object disappears after php file inclusion

Tags: php, include, database-connection, mysqli, require

I have an index.php, which at it's very start includes db.php - file which simply creates a database connection object $db.

Now, later on in the script I include page.php, and it doesn't recognize $db, giving me "undefined variable" error.

My question is why $db disappears and can I prevent it somehow? None of the mentioned pages does anything else database related.

My understanding of scripting is that each included file should be treated like part of index.php - but the very moment page.php is included, $db disappears.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I include page.php using function:

```
function load_page_content($page) {
require "pages/$page.php";
}
```

I'm using only relative paths.

The way I am using $db is:

```
$test1 = $db->stmt_init();
```

and it works fine everywhere except in included page.php

Comment: You will need to show some code. Are you including file paths and not http:// ones? Are you in a function with any of this?

Comment: Pekka thanks for looking into this, I've expanded question with this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Pekka's comment helped me sort this out, instead of calling function that includes page, I've put include directly to index.php and now it works.

Thanks!